# Trying to turn an XML to a JTable that allows user input

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jtable

I got an XML file which is like this

```js
<data>
  <columns>
    <Brand index="5">Brand</Brand>
    <BuyCurrency index="13">BuyCurrency</BuyCurrency>
    <BuyPrice index="12">BuyPrice</BuyPrice>
    <Category index="3">Category</Category>
    <Id index="1">Id</Id>
    <LeadTime index="16">LeadTime</LeadTime>
    <MinOrderQuantity index="7">MinOrderQuantity</MinOrderQuantity>
    <Name index="2">Name</Name>
    <SellCurrency index="11">SellCurrency</SellCurrency>
    <SellPrice index="10">SellPrice</SellPrice>
    <StockOnHand index="14">StockOnHand</StockOnHand>
    <StockOnOrder index="15">StockOnOrder</StockOnOrder>
    <SubCategory index="4">SubCategory</SubCategory>
    <Supplier index="6">Supplier</Supplier>
    <TargetBatchVolume index="8">TargetBatchVolume</TargetBatchVolume>
    <Volume index="9">Volume</Volume>
  </columns>
  <records>
    <record index="1">
      <Brand>StarTAC</Brand>
      <BuyCurrency>GBP</BuyCurrency>
      <BuyPrice>27.67</BuyPrice>
      <Category>Technology</Category>
      <Id>16342939</Id>
      <LeadTime>15</LeadTime>
      <MinOrderQuantity>1</MinOrderQuantity>
      <Name>StarTAC Series</Name>
      <SellCurrency>USD</SellCurrency>
      <SellPrice>65.99</SellPrice>
      <StockOnHand>15</StockOnHand>
      <StockOnOrder>50</StockOnOrder>
      <SubCategory>Telephones and Communication</SubCategory>
      <Supplier>Office First</Supplier>
      <TargetBatchVolume>0</TargetBatchVolume>
      <Volume>0.8</Volume>
    </record>
    <record index="2">
      <Brand>Xerox</Brand>
      <BuyCurrency>CNY</BuyCurrency>
      <BuyPrice>29.8</BuyPrice>
      <Category>Office Supplies</Category>
      <Id>16346727</Id>
      <LeadTime>5</LeadTime>
      <MinOrderQuantity>1</MinOrderQuantity>
      <Name>Xerox 1984</Name>
      <SellCurrency>USD</SellCurrency>
      <SellPrice>6.48</SellPrice>
      <StockOnHand>34</StockOnHand>
      <StockOnOrder>1</StockOnOrder>
      <SubCategory>Paper</SubCategory>
      <Supplier>Drecom</Supplier>
      <TargetBatchVolume>67.5</TargetBatchVolume>
      <Volume>0.47</Volume>
    </record>
    <record index="3">
      <Brand>Xerox</Brand>
      <BuyCurrency>CNY</BuyCurrency>
      <BuyPrice>219.54</BuyPrice>
      <Category>Office Supplies</Category>
      <Id>16346853</Id>
      <LeadTime>10</LeadTime>
      <MinOrderQuantity>1</MinOrderQuantity>
      <Name>Xerox 1885</Name>
      <SellCurrency>USD</SellCurrency>
      <SellPrice>48.04</SellPrice>
      <StockOnHand>16</StockOnHand>
      <StockOnOrder>40</StockOnOrder>
      <SubCategory>Paper</SubCategory>
      <Supplier>Drecom</Supplier>
      <TargetBatchVolume>67.5</TargetBatchVolume>
      <Volume>0.55</Volume>
    </record>
    <record index="4">
      <Brand>Elite</Brand>
      <BuyCurrency>CNY</BuyCurrency>
      <BuyPrice>34.12</BuyPrice>
      <Category>Office Supplies</Category>
      <Id>16350870</Id>
      <LeadTime>12</LeadTime>
      <MinOrderQuantity>1</MinOrderQuantity>
      <Name>Elite 5 inch Scissors</Name>
      <SellCurrency>USD</SellCurrency>
      <SellPrice>8.45</SellPrice>
      <StockOnHand>0</StockOnHand>
      <StockOnOrder>3</StockOnOrder>
      <SubCategory>Scissors, Rulers and Trimmers</SubCategory>
      <Supplier>FHL</Supplier>
      <TargetBatchVolume>0</TargetBatchVolume>
      <Volume>0.85</Volume>
    </record>
    <record index="5">
      <Brand>Wilson</Brand>
      <BuyCurrency>CNY</BuyCurrency>
      <BuyPrice>31.3</BuyPrice>
      <Category>Office Supplies</Category>
      <Id>16359070</Id>
      <LeadTime>33</LeadTime>
      <MinOrderQuantity>10</MinOrderQuantity>
      <Name>Wilson Jones DublLock D-Ring Binders</Name>
      <SellCurrency>USD</SellCurrency>
      <SellPrice>6.75</SellPrice>
      <StockOnHand>30</StockOnHand>
      <StockOnOrder>0</StockOnOrder>
      <SubCategory>Binders and Binder Accessories</SubCategory>
      <Supplier>SuperSupply</Supplier>
      <TargetBatchVolume>0</TargetBatchVolume>
      <Volume>0.12</Volume>
    </record>
    <record index="6">
      <Brand>MicroTAC</Brand>
      <BuyCurrency>CNY</BuyCurrency>
      <BuyPrice>261.48</BuyPrice>
      <Category>Technology</Category>
      <Id>16376266</Id>
      <LeadTime>5</LeadTime>
      <MinOrderQuantity>1</MinOrderQuantity>
      <Name>MicroTAC 650</Name>
      <SellCurrency>USD</SellCurrency>
      <SellPrice>65.99</SellPrice>
      <StockOnHand>5</StockOnHand>
      <StockOnOrder>1</StockOnOrder>
      <SubCategory>Telephones and Communication</SubCategory>
      <Supplier>Drecom</Supplier>
      <TargetBatchVolume>67.5</TargetBatchVolume>
      <Volume>0.55</Volume>
    </record>
```

And then I parsed it with DOM Parser and it becomes:

```js
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class inventoryread {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

 File fXmlFile = new File("sample.xml");
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

 System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");

 System.out.println("----------------------------");

 for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
  List<String> record = new ArrayList<>();

  Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

  System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

  if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

   Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

   System.out.println("record index " + eElement.getAttribute("index"));
   System.out.println("Buy Currency : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("BuyCurrency").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("Buy Price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("BuyPrice").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("Category : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Category").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("Id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("LeadTime : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("LeadTime").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("MinOrderQuantity : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("MinOrderQuantity").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("SellCurrency : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SellCurrency").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("SellPrice : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SellPrice").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("StockOnHand : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("StockOnHand").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("StockOnOrder : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("StockOnOrder").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("SubCategory : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("SubCategory").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("Supplier : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Supplier").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("TargetBatchVolume : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("TargetBatchVolume").item(0).getTextContent());
   System.out.println("Volume : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Volume").item(0).getTextContent());
  
  }
  
 }
    } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Now I need to turn the data into a JTable with user able to change the data and I did researches and just totally got stuck. Would someone please give me some help and solutions?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Extract Your data to String[][] data, this will be values You need to show to user, and column names to String[]columnName, which will be name for each column.
First method will create JFrame in which your table will be shown, and second method can be used to retrieve data, if you need to save it.

```
String [][] data = new String[][]{{"Test11", "Test12", "Test13", "Test14"},
            {"Test21", "Test22", "Test23", "Test24"},
            {"Test31", "Test32", "Test33", "Test34"}};
String[] columnName = new String[] {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column3"};


private void createDataTable(String[][] data, String[] columnName){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnName);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane);

    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public String[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    TableModel dtm = table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    String[][] tableData = new String[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
    return tableData;
}
```

Comment: I tired to run but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I made some mistake when I put the code in

Comment: Code works for data and columnName that I've posted. Is it possible that you did not extract data to arrays correctly